# headerLines.reverse() error in stomp.js

Tags: react-native

undefined is not a function (evaluating 'headerLines.reverse()typeof Symbol === 'function' ? Symbol.iterator :'@@iterator'')

When I connect two android devices simultaneously, I encounter this error.

Please help me!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing was happening to me but I realized it happened when remote debugging was **disabled**. Managed to make it work by replacing [webstomp-client](https://github.com/JSteunou/webstomp-client) with [stompjs](https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I solved this error by copying es6 code of webstomp-client to project.